# Making JSON code 'cleanly displayed' on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to get this code cleaner, it does display on the html page.

```
app.get("/web/users", function(req, res) {
var users = app.models.users.model('User');
users.find({}).lean().exec(function(err, result){
res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
res.end();
```

This does work, and it lists something like this...

[{"_id":"...","name":"Justin","phonenumber":"5555555555","useSMS":true,"callerId":["..."],"PIN":"..."}]

Now, I would like this code to display like this...

Justin 5555555555

Comment: now you just need to treat your json string as an object eg: `result.name` and `result.phonenumber`

Comment: @Mouseroot oh, I think I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly and you want your json pretty-printed, here:

```
res.write(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

That will indent your JSON hierarchically using 2 spaces.

EDIT: re-reading with Mouseroot's comment, I think what you actually want is:

```
res.write(result.name + ' ' + result.phonenumber);
```

Comment: yea alsong as he uses `result = JSON.stringify(result);` he can treat the JSON string as an object, if your in chrome you could do a `console.dir(result)` to get an even better view of how everything is structured for more complex JSON objects.